# ERC20 payment mechanism solution

Tags: erc-20, metamask, java, trustwallet

I want to implement payment mechanism on my web site .
after too many search on internet . i understood payment gateways like `cryptomus` or `bitpay` generate new address peer payment order . then never use that address again . (If i confused , please notice me)

**My question is** why should not use this address again ?!
what happened if i have a flow like this:

1. customer click to pay
2. backend server send request to wallet provider `like metamask` for generate new address then create a invoice and hold both in database.
3. **lock generated address on database** (prevent send to wrong customer)
4. send address to ui (generate qr code)
5. customer scan qr code then pay .
6. backend listen to etherscan.io according to generated address
7. if (paied) {**unlock address (wait to next order)**} elese {wait to timeout reached}

###### advantage:

- never generate million addresses on the fly !
- if another customer requested to pay:
  we can search on db :

  - if any free address exists so used that .
  - else request to wallet provider to generate new address .

###### Disadvantages :

- need more gas fee for collect from addresses to main business address.
- if customer send to previous wrong address (note: exists on my db), so we need tx id to approve that . (maybe manual operation)

---

Actually i am java developer .
this is my interface :

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * ERC20 Payment Interface
 */
public interface PaymentInterface {
    /**
     * Create new account on metamask wallet
     *
     * @return return payment account
     */
    MetamaskAccount generateNewAccount();

    /**
     * store new account on database
     * @param account new account generated on metamask
     */
    void storeAccount(MetamaskAccount account);
    /**
     * @return List all metamask generated wallets
     */
    List<MetamaskAccount> getAccounts();

    /**
     * @return list of metamask {@link MetamaskAccount lock} field is false
     */
    List<MetamaskAccount> getFreeAccounts();

    /**
     * @param lock switch state of MetamaskAccount to lock or unlock
     */
    void changeStatus(boolean lock);
}
```

and this is my simple model :

```
public class MetamaskAccount {
    /**
     * Metamask account private key.
     * Note: public key generated from private key.
     */
    private String privateKey;
    /**
     * Account address
     */
    private String address ;

    /**
     * Lock wallet until :
     *  1) transaction committed
     *  2) transaction time out
     */
    private boolean lock;
    /**
     * Account timeout (as seconds).
     * this account locked if timeout reached
     * Example : 1800 second (30 minutes to pay)
     */
    private long timeout;
    /**
     * Start lock date & time
     */
    private LocalDateTime lockTime;

    // Getter && Setter
}
```

this solution only need a cron job executed every 1 minutes only for check timeouts .
Is there a problem that I have not noticed?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO simply because users act not as machines and they will be funding the address after their timeout has passed. Don't ask me how:)

And it's cheap to generate a private key & address. It's just running a function on the backend.

Collecting payments from an address does increase the cost of payments though. Well, you can stitch it into your service fee.